# Recursively finding lowest number in linked list

Tags: c++, list, recursion, linked-list

I am trying to find the lowest value in a linked list that i created, i need to find this recursively, any ideas on how to go about this?

Here is what i have for my header

```
// Header file for the IntList class

#ifndef INTLIST_H
#define INTLIST_H

#include <iostream>

class IntList
{
    private:
        struct ListNode // Used for nodes
        {
            int value;
            ListNode * next;
        };
        ListNode * head; // Address of the 1st node
        int sum, high_value;
        int lowValues(ListNode *);
    public:
        IntList();                  //Constructor
        IntList(IntList &);         //Copy constructor
        void appendNode(int);       //Adds a new node to end of list
        void insertNode(int);       //Inserts a num into list
        void deleteNode(int);       //Deletes a num from list
        void displayList() const;   //Displays list
        int sumList();              //Returns sum of list
        int highValue();            //Finds highest value in the list
        ***int lowValue(ListNode *)    //Finds low value using recursion***
        { return lowValue(head); }
        ~IntList();                 //Destructor
};
```

Comment: Unless the compiler manages to undo the recursion, all recursion gives you is a decrease in performance and a risk of overflowing the stack that doesn't exist with the iterative version.

Comment: sounds like homework.

Comment: @user1920482 Ah. That would make sense I suppose. Educational exercises on recursion always seem to pick examples where recursion would be a bad idea, for some reason.

Comment: A forward iteration would be simpler.  Sorting the list would be advisable.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews sorting it would likely be O(n ln n) while just looking for it (whether iteratively or recursively) would be O(n). So, unless the sorted list had further uses, the sort would be a waste.

Answer (score 2):

Don't roll your own linked list in C++. There are two in the standard library - std::list is a doubly linked list, std::forward_list is singly-linked. There's also a standard algorithm to find the min element in a range:

```
std::list<int> intList = {1, 2, 3};

int minimum = *(std::min_element(std::begin(inList), std::end(intList)));
```

I see your list class has more information stored than just the list, but by using this algorithm and a standard container, you don't need your class at all. Unless of course, this is an assignment to write a linked list class ;)

Comment: You might have meant to suggest using a `std::forward_list`, since his original data structure is a singly linked list. Otherwise, +1 for suggesting not to reinvent the wheel. :-)

Comment: I did mention that :)

Comment: If this is homework, they may be barred from using the standard containers.  That makes me a little sad, unless it's a data structures class intended to teach you what's inside the containers.

Comment: @polkadotcadaver: Dang, my bad!

Answer (score 1):

High level sketch:

- If I'm the last element of the list, return myself as the "lowest"
- Otherwise, return the smaller of myself and "the rest of the list."

That's the essence.  If you get stuck writing that, show us where you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm possibly going to embarrass myself with rusty C++, but the crux of this is language-agnostic, so the gist should be comprehensible).

```
private:
static int lowValueForNode(ListNode* node)
{
  ListNode* next = node->next;
  if(next == 0)
    return node->value;
  int fromNext = lowValueForNode(next);
  return fromNext < node->value ? fromNext : node-> value;
}
public:
int lowValue()
{
  return lowValueForNode(head);
}
```

The call into `lowValue()` starts with a call into `lowValueForNode()` with `head` as the argument. This in turn calls into `lowValueForNode()` again with the next node as it's argument, and keeps doing so until the last node is reached, in which case it just returns that nodes value.

As each call returns, the return is compared with the value of the current node, so that the lower of the two is returned, and so on until the lowest value in the list is the final result.

However, this is not a good idea. All of those function calls are a needless expense that at a certain size of list would cause the call-stack to overflow. It would be much better to use:

```
int lowValue()
{
  int ret = head->value;
  for(ListNode* node = head->next; node != 0; node = node->next)
    if(node->value < ret)
      ret = node->value;
  return ret;
}
```

(I'm assuming `head` is never null in both cases here, mostly because I don't know what you want to do in the case of an empty list. Either way could catch that at the beginning of `lowValue`).

Faster, safer, and simpler. Recursion is great because it's often much easier to solve a problem by thinking recursively than iteratively, but the compiler can't always turn it into the iterative version, so if a problem has a natural iterative solution, it's premature pessimisation to use recursion.

(At least, in imperative languages; in some declarative languages recursion is both a more natural approach, and more likely to be the superior or perhaps even the only approach).

Answer (score 0):

Your lowValues would look like this,

```
int lowValues(ListNode *n){
if(n!=NULL){
int k=lowValues(n->next);
return (k<n->value)?k:n->value;
}
}
```

this is mostly C-code, but it works

Comment: You might want to handle the case where `n==NULL` too.

Comment: there is no need for that

Comment: Not strictly, though the compiler should give a warning, and the results is undefined. That undefined result could be lower than all the values, so the method would give the wrong answer.